# File validation via Regular Expression - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using an upload plugin to upload files in jquery.

This gets the type of the file uploaded (e.g. jpeg):

```
data.files[0].type
```

I need to check if it's a valid image file type (usal image file types jpeg, jpeg, gif, png) using a reg expression.

So far I have:

```
var isValid = (/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(data.files[0].type);
```

But it's not working (always returns false).

Any ideas on how to fix?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use the jQuey validation plugin, namely the [extension](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/CustomMethods/extension#extension) method?

Comment: Make sure data.files[0].type returns a string starting with a dot, like ".jpg". Try casting it as a string, maybe.

Comment: Just so that you're aware, that checks the file **extension**, not its type.

Comment: @adrianp it's not going to work with my image uplaoder plug in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your type of the file uploaded (e.g. jpeg) without "dot" so you need that:

```
var isValid = (/(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(data.files[0].type)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp is properly constructed (though it only checks extension, not type, as already mentioned), so it is obvious that you're checking wrong data.

Print out `data.files[0].type` and see if it really is what you think it is. Judging from variable name it is very likely that you have file extension without leading dot that your regexp checks for there.

Comment: Yes, it's without the . so it looks like 'jpeg' What do I need to do to my expression?